# Python/Django subscripe permanently to a MQTT Mosquito topic and get data

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, mqtt

In my django project i would to subscribe to an MQTT topic forever and trigger actions when topic change.
In my `__init__.py` application file i try:

```
client1 = mqtt.Client(hex(uuid.getnode()))
data_dict = init_client('IOT/Data/#')

for k, v in data_dict.items():
    ...do some stuff with data
```

the `init_client` function connect to my MQTT server and start loop ( i use paho.mqtt.client):

```
def init_client(t_topic='IOT/Data/#'):
# Instantiate and check connection about MQTT instance
client1.on_connect = on_connect  # attach function to callback
client1.on_message = on_message  # attach function to callback
if t_topic == 'IOT/Data/#':
    client1.message_callback_add(t_topic, on_message_data)
else:
    client1.message_callback_add(t_topic, on_message_reg)
client1.on_publish = on_publish  # attach function to callback
# client1.on_subscribe =on_subscribe
# attach function to callback
try:
    client1.tls_set(mqtt_ca_crt, mqtt_cli_crt, mqtt_cli_key)
    client1.tls_insecure_set(True)
except ValueError:
    logging.info("SSL/TLS Already configured")
time.sleep(1)

try:
    if not client1.is_connected():
        client1.connect(mqtt_server, mqtt_port)  # connect to broker
        client1.connected_flag = False
    
except Exception:
    logging.error("Cannot connect MQTT Client1")

client1.loop_forever()
...and some other stuff
```

the problem is when loop_forever() start all django application got in hold, whaiting forever.

So my question is:
How can i subscibe to a topic with paho.mqtt (asynchronously) when my django allpication start and get notified every time the topic change in real time?
There are others more smart way with django to do this?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the Python Paho [doc](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#network-loop)

> *loop_start() / loop_stop()*
>
> ```
> loop_start()
> loop_stop(force=False)
> ```
>
> These functions implement a threaded interface to the network loop.
> Calling loop_start() once, before or after connect*(), runs a thread
> in the background to call loop() automatically. This frees up the main
> thread for other work that may be blocking. This call also handles
> reconnecting to the broker. Call loop_stop() to stop the background
> thread. The force argument is currently ignored.